# Low Latency Desktopstreaming with ffmpeg (p2p)

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm trying to stream my Desktop from one Pc to another with udp. Unfortunately the Latency is pretty high (I already could reduce it from about 15 Seconds to 2 Seconds, in tests where I run client and host on the same PC.
My Hostcommand looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -framerate 24 -i video=screen-capture-recorder -vf scale=1280:720 -vcodec libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f mpegts udp://239.255.1.2:1234
```

My Clientcommand looks like this:

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -infbuf -fast -framedrop -vf "setpts=(PTS*0.95)" udp://239.255.1.2:1234
```

Any Ideas, how to get this even faster?

Comment: You'd find people on SO be more willing to help you if you reward them for previous answers first. It's a single click with your mouse in return for their time and effort.

Comment: Ehrm yes, I'm sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link can help you to explore another ideas like buffer use, scaling strategy, compiling ffmpeg according OS described in compilation guide, etc.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites

On the other side, may be you could consider to generate small videos (each one part of the streaming).

The idea is that client application begins to reproduce the first video until it has been downloaded completely, while at the same time in another process, the following small video starts to download simultaneously. The second video will be played until it has been downloades completely, and so on.

Of course, I think it is important display messages when the network service affect the funcionality of your application video streaming.

Some years ago, I did something like this using network camera axis, swf videos and ffmpeg. The "live streaming video" recorder was in .net, while the player video was in php (server) and javascript (client).

Comment: I already found them, but I could not manage to improve my Stream. Thank you anyways :)